# Trigger To Update Stock Inventory When Insert Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I saw several posts on this, but still have problems in my case. I 2 tables SALES_STOCKS and STOCKS. I would like when someone purchase a product from table SALES_STOCKS (it has a column NUMBER_STOCKS), the other table STOCKS to update QUANTITY column. In other words, it should update SALES_STOCKS.NUMBER_STOCKS - STOCKS.QUANTITY

Here is a screenshot of my database:

[My database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sAPv140FMIze8VuW-bOl7rHRU3rpv2l6)

Here is my what I managed to do with my trigger:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER trg_updStocks ON SALES_STOCKS
  AFTER INSERT AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted
            LEFT OUTER JOIN deleted
            ON inserted.NUMBER_STOCKS = deleted.NUMBER_STOCKS
            WHERE deleted.NUMBER_STOCKS IS NULL)
      UPDATE STOCKS
      SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - NEW.QUANTITY 
      WHERE ID = New.ID;
  END
  GO
```

Comment: Instead of a trigger, you might want to consider a stored procedure, that performs both the purchase and the inventory update in a single transaction.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew I would create an update command after the insert all in one SP which your application uses

Answer (score 0):

There is no `deleted` in an `insert` trigger.  There is no `new` in SQL Server triggers.

I think you just want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_updStocks ON SALES_STOCKS
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE s
      SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - i.insert_quantity 
      FROM STOCKS s JOIN
           (SELECT i.stock_id, SUM(i.quantity) as insert_quantity
            FROM inserted i
            GROUP BY i.stock_id
           ) i
           ON s.ID = i.ID;
END;
```

For update and delete triggers, you can use similar logic on the `deleted` table.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. You are great.